# Incrementing value in a Horizon collection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rethinkdb, horizon

I am trying to figure out how to perform the basic task of incrementing a value in horizon.io collection. For instance, I have an `<h1>` tag that could represent an upvotes button, and I want the upvotes count to be persistent.

```
<h1 @click="inc">{{foo}}</h1> <!-- foo is local variable -->
    <ul>
      <li v-for="message in me">
      {{message.value}} <!-- message.value is upvote value from collection --> 
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Then in the Vue instance:

```
created() {
  me.store({
    datetime: new Date(),
    value: this.foo // local data variable set to 0 initially. 
  }).subscribe(
      result => console.log(result),

      error => console.log(error)
    )
 var self = this
 me.watch().subscribe(function(data){
      data.map(function(data){
        self.foo = data.value
      })
  })  
},
```

Then I am trying to update the value each time the `<h1>` tag is clicked:

```
inc(){
  me.update({
    id: 1,
    value: this.foo++
  })
}
```

How do I update a value in the collection, and do I have to render the collection in my template in order to have access to the value in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can avoid the `var self = this` headache by just using the new [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this). `this` even within functions of functions will still use the outermost `this`:

```js
created() {
  me.store({
    datetime: new Date(),
    value: this.foo // local data variable set to 0 initially. 
  }).subscribe(
    result => console.log(result),
    error => console.log(error)
  );
  me.watch().subscribe((data) => {
    data.map((data) => {
      this.foo = data.value;
    })
  })  
},
```

Your increment `.update` function looks correct but I'd do this instead:

```
inc(){
  this.foo++;
  me.update({
    id: 1,
    value: this.foo
  });
}
```

Post-fix and pre-fix can get tricky, and I'm not sure if it would result in the output you'd expect since it would [*return the value of `this.foo` and then increment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()).

> How do I update a value in the collection, and do I have to render the collection in my template in order to have access to the value in the collection?

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you're using `.update` correctly so you know how already! But from my experience in Vue, you do not have to render the collection to have access to the value? `this.foo` is being reassigned every time the document with `id: 1` changes. But if you don't supply an `id` when you initially `.store` an object, we will provide one for the document. So your initial `.store` code should probably look like this:
    try {
      me.insert({
        id: 1,
        datetime: new Date(),
        value: this.foo // local data variable set to 0 initially. 
      }).subscribe(
        result => console.log(result),
        error => console.log(error)
      );
    } catch(e) {
     console.log("Already exists!", e); 
    }

Also you only want to subscribe to changes to that one `id: 1` document:

me.find(1).watch().subscribe((data) => {
  data.map((data) => {
    this.foo = data.value;
  });
});

Does that answer your question?

EDIT: Forgot, to change `.watch`

EDIT2: Changing `.store` (which overwrites the data every single time) to `.insert` which will insert if the document doesn't exist and error if it does. We want this functionality because we just want to insert if it doesn't exist and do nothing if it does, versus overwriting the `value` field.

Comment: I get strange behaviour when attaching a click handler to the value that I get from the collection. The increment works but the updated value does not persist. If I click on it in one browser, the value increments, but if I open it in another browser, the value goes back down, but not necessarily back down to zero. In fact, the value bounces around in an unpredictable manner. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: I have the odd incrementing issue resolved, but the value does not persist. If I refresh the browser, the value goes back to zero.

Comment: Hey @MahmudAdam I made a silly mistake in assuming you'd only run the `.store` once, but if you look at my update above, you'll see we want to use `.insert` and catch if it already exists and continue running. Basically every time you load the page, you're overwriting the document that already exists which is why the value is always going back to zero.